# Can I use 8GB 1666 MHz DDR3 on Macbook Pro Early 2011 15?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I want to upgrade my RAM of Macbook Pro Early 2011 15 inch. On apple website it says to use 1333 Mhz, unfortunately I cant find it in my local market , they are offereing 1666 Mhz of 8GB and saying that it is backward compatible.
Can I use 1666Mhz in my Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use.

They need to be SO-DIMM DDR3, if your CPU doesn't support 1666 MHz they will be clocked down to 1333 MHz.

About your model (Macbook Pro Early 2011 15 inch) looks like the 2.0 GHz CPU version supports only 1333 MHz, versions with 2.2 GHz or 2.3 GHz CPU support 1666 MHz

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a very old thread, but information may be useful to others.

You can actually use 16 GB ... I am using 16 GB on my 2011 15 in MBP.  macsales.com sells the proper RAM as does crucial.com.  Apple specs say "8 max" because that is all that was available at the time and they never updated specs but 16 GB has been working well for many.